# 3x3 Slider Puzzle, is this impossible to solve?

Tags: sliding-puzzle

So I was playing a puzzle app on my phone, and I couldn't solve a puzzle (I'd been working on it for quite a while too)

it looked like this

[image]

The bottom two pieces needed to be swapped, but no matter what I did, I couldn't get them to swap (unless I messed up some other part). So I checked online for a 3x3 slider solver, and it told me it was impossible to solve it...

Answer (score 2):

Using the method from [this post on slider puzzle solvability](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html), your puzzle has 3 inversions and is therefore **unsolvable**.

```
Order      1 2 3 4 5 8 7 6 9
Inversions 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0
```